# Extend WooCommerce REST API for product categories with custom meta

Tags: woocommerce, rest

I'm trying to display in WC REST API the meta fields I have created for product categories but can not find a solution.

All I find are solutions for products, not for product categories.

Is it possible? If yes, can you give a direction where to look please?

Thanks

Comment: Which route did you send your request to? Also, it'd be great if we could see your code snippet in order to debug it for you!!!

Comment: Hi Ruvee. By route you mean how do I retrieve json data? I request it with url "https://nexdna.dev/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories". It successfully returns all the default data related to product categories but not the custom meta I added. As for the snippet, I simply don't have it as this is exactly what I'm looking for. Otherwise I would formulate my question differently.